# Set default value of input field with read-only attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, html, forms, default

I have a form that posts persistent data to an SQL database. In my form I have an input field that is at first set to read-only, unless the user selects an option:

[image]

My problem is that if the user chooses not to enter a value in the input field, I receive this error:

[image]

I tried setting the default value of the input in my javascript, but i receive the same error.

```
$("#lejeperiode").val(" ");
```

It doesn't matter whether an empty string or null is inserted into the DB.
This is my input field:

```html
<input id="periodeInput" class="form-control" type="text" name="lejeperiode" value="@(Request.Form["lejeperiode"] != null ? Request.Form["lejeperiode"].ToString() : "")"/>
```

Comment: string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["xxx"]) ? "" : Request.Form["xxx"].ToString()

Comment: try `$("#lejeperiode").value;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code to check if string is empty if so "" will be your default else POST value.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lejeperiode", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["lejeperiode"]) ? "" : Request.Form["lejeperiode"].ToString())
```